# Committed files are not added on update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

We are using VS 2010 for SharePoint development. We are using SVN with AnkhSVN plugin.
One of the developers created new feature and committed solution. I updated solution to latest version, and I can see in project histry that new directory is ADDED and files in it are ADDED, but those files are not physically in the path they should be. Those files are also marked as DELETED on my Pending Changes list... Any idea why this might happened and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to Revert the changes in Pending, and do another update?

Comment: Actually reverting fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Revert the changes in Pending, and do another update.